# Excel Hyperlink does not work

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have been batling this suposedly simple problem for 2 hours now and I just cant figure it out. I am trying to make a link and no matter how many " marks I try it always ends up in error or the link says `& Poracun(Z).Ime &` Can anyone find me a way that I can change the link name ?
Here is my code:

```
Cells(i, "B").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""[" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DN_Pokalkulacija.xlsx" & "]" & "'" & "Sheet1" & "'" & "!E" & Poracun(Z).Vrstica & ""","" & Poracun(Z).Ime & "")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. Your `"` delimiting is not quite right
2. Formula expects `'` around the file name, not the sheet.  Like `'[FileName]SheetName'!`

Try

```
Cells(5, "B").Formula = "=HYPERLINK('[" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DN_Pokalkulacija.xlsx" & "]" & "Sheet1" & "'" & "!E" & Poracun(Z).Vrstica & ",""" & Poracun(Z).Ime & """)"
```

Comment: thank you but your solution completly disrupts the link, i think its the reagon problem .

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out , it was quotation problem, i forgot all about it and now i have read up on it inside quotation string you need to make double quotation to use as single in final string. Here is a working link :

```
g = "=HYPERLINK(""[" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DN_Pokalkulacija.xlsx" & "]" & "'" & "Sheet1" & "'" & "!E" & Poracun(Z).Vrstica & """,""" & Poracun(Z).Ime & """)"
```

It was all in quotation (") marks :)